# How do you add two logins with http basic authentications in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create two logins for my app. One that can be used to access the index show and edit pages. And another login just for the new page. I'd really like to accomplish this with http basic authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you can do something like:

```
before_filter :authenticate1, only: [:index, :show, :edit]
before_filter :authenticate2, only: [:new]

def authenticate1
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
    session[:user] = 'admin' if user_name == 'admin' && password == 'admin'
  end
end

def authenticate2
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
    session[:user] = 'other' if user_name == 'other' && password == 'other'
  end
end
```